# VBA Object type

Tags: vba

I've stumbled upon some behaviour I do not understand. Consider the following function:

```
Function identity(n As Integer) As Integer
  identity = n
End Function
```

Obviously this isn't the most practically useful function, but it highlights my problem well.

This works as I would expect, simply returning the input of it is an integer, otherwise throwing an error.

However, if I change the output to be an Object, I would still expect this to work, since, as I understand it, integers are objects. Alas, instead I get an 'error in Value'.

This also occurs if both the input and output types are changed to Objects.

The function exhibits truly curious behaviour when the input is changed to an Object but the output remains an integer. If it is called from excel via '=identity(3)' it errors, but if it is called via '=identity(A1)' where A1 contains 3, it returns the correct value.

Can anyone explain what is going on? I'm new to VB, but I've programmed in many different languages previously and I've never seen anything like this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `n` is an Object and `identity` returns an Object then in VBA:

```
Set identity = n
```

Object types need to use `Set` and non-object types like `Integer` do not use `Set`

*edit* In response to comment below, 3 is an Integer literal. Integer is not an Object type and can't be treated as one.

You may find the [Variant type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251448.aspx) to be useful as it can hold both Object and non-object types. You can then use [TypeName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278698.aspx) to work out exactly what you are dealing with and proceed accordingly

Comment: This still fails for '=identity(3)'. Is there some root class I can use? I would have thought that was Object...

Comment: I've added some more details about object vs. non-object in VBA

Answer (score 4):

If this is to serve some larger purpose, perhaps you can use the variant type.

```
Function identity(v As Variant) As Variant
    identity = v
End Function

?identity("K") & "E"
KE

?identity("2") + 2
 4 
?identity(2) + 2
 4 
?identity(2) & 2
22 

?identity("K") & 2
K2

?identity("K") + 2
Run-time error '13': Type mismatch
```

VBA is considered a [loose-typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) (aka 'weak-typed') programming language so adding "2" + 2 and 2 + 2 produce the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Integers are not objects in VBA. `Set` implicitly sets a pointer to an object (user-defined or built-in). An `Integer` variable stores it's value more directly.